# forcing mic input in Android

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, microphone, recording

I have a weird setup where I am trying to record audio from an external device using a TRRS male-male audio cable. The way it is supposed to work, I plug in the audio cable to the device, then to the phone then use AudioRecorder to record in audio. On my HTC One M8 everything works great and I can record audio from the device. On my Samsung Galaxy S2 it records audio but from the internal mic.

I confirmed the issue is with the impedance of the mic input. If I add a resistor to the audio cable to increase the mic impedance then the S2 will record from the device correctly.

So my question is: Is there anyway to force Android to use the external mic jack? I looked into sending the ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG intent with the microphone set to -1 for external, but fail due to permission errors. It seems this intent was moved into protected permissions (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/8f014059d3084fcce9e82b4b1f8b8323744ac52d)

So is there any other way to force the phone to use the mic jack without external hardware?!

Thanks!

Also, for the actual audio recording, settings are:
44100kHz sample rate
16 bit samples
Mono channel
Buffer is set to AudioRecord.MinBufferSize()